# multiple Domains without repeat config

Tags: nginx

How can I serve multiple domains with the same configuration, without copying the server{} rule configuration for every domain?

- example.com
- example.org
- example.de
- example.ro

Nginx Config:

```
upstream example_live {
    server 127.0.0.1:8300;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com example.org example.de example.ro;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/example.access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/example.error.log;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://example_live/VirtualHostBase/http/example.??:80/example/VirtualHostRoot/;
        include /etc/nginx/ps.cfg/proxy.conf;
    }
    include /etc/nginx/cfg/base.conf;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in the same server section and using [server_name](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html) directive to support multiple domains. And seems you already give the answer above.

Comment: But with the proxy_pass statement i have to insert a single url (xxx.?? -> xxx.com) this url will be used as "main" domain for all further requests..  

1st request -> xxx.org  
proxy_pass ... /VirtualHostBase/http/xxx.com:80/...  

all other request use to xxx.com

Comment: you can add a rewrite command to rewrite the other hosts to the main host. Just like: if ( $host ~ "***.org|de" ) { rewrite "^.*$" http://***.com permanent;}

Answer (score 0):

This works for me, thank you for your Comment

```
server_name a.com www.a.com
            b.org www.b.org
            c.net www.c.net;

access_log /var/log/nginx/a.com.access.log;
error_log /var/log/nginx/a.com.error.log;

location / {
    rewrite           ^(.*)$ /VirtualHostBase/http/$http_host:80/a/VirtualHostRoot$1 break;
    proxy_pass        http://127.0.0.1:8080;
}
```

Comment: I have a configuration with 14 different TLDs running - I think there is no limitation.

Comment: doesn't seems like a solution for longterm， anyone have a bad idea?

Comment: What if I have thousands of domains , what should I do.

Comment: Try nginx with LUA https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/dynamic-modules/lua/